# How to create a custom navigation drawer in android

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

Hi I'm trying to create a navigation drawer similar to gmail app navigation drawer. I follow the developer site but it only specify about basic implementation. But I need to customize the navigation  according to my specifications.

1. I need to add a header to categorize the list item in Drawer
2. I need a radio button to select some of my options

How can I do this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The tutorial [Android Custom Navigation Drawer (via archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20171208103611/http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/) contains a **basic** and a **custom** project. The latter shows how to setup a Navigation Drawer as shown in the screenshot:

[image: NavigationDrawerCustom]

The [source code of the projects (via archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150403005813/http://downloads.tutecentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/NavigationDrawerExample.zip) is available for download.

---

The is also the [Navigation Drawer - Live-O](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.liveo.navigationliveo) project ...

[image: Navigation Drawer - Live-O]

The [source code of the project](http://github.com/rudsonlive/Navigation-Drawer-ActionBarCompat) is available on GitHub.

---

The [MaterialDrawer library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) aims to provide the easiest possible implementation of a navigation drawer for your application. It provides a great amount of out of the box customizations and also includes an easy to use header which can be used as AccountSwitcher.

[image: MaterialDrawer library demo]

---

Please note that **Android Studio** meanwhile has a **template project** to create a *Navigation Drawer Activity* as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Navigation Drawer Activity]

This [repository](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/AndroidStudioNavigationDrawer) keeps track of changes being made to the template.

Comment: I have similar and strange issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863616/background-image-and-image-view-in-navigation-drawer/: I managed to get the drawer working but have couple of errors. Not sure how to fix it?

Comment: OK! I know I can do it simply in android studio but how about if I what to change the navigation drawer font?

Comment: @AmirH Please open a new question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @JJD, please update the link to the source code. It seems broken. http://downloads.tutecentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/NavigationDrawerExample.zip

Comment: @user5038993 There is nothing I can do about it. I suggest you contact the author of the article or leave a comment [on the website](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/).

Comment: The original tutecentral.com article is no longer online. I replaced the links with their latest archived version.

Answer (score 52):

I used below layout and able to achieve custom layout in Navigation View.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navi_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start|top"
        android:background="@color/navigation_view_bg_color"
        app:theme="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/drawer_header" />

            <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_menu" />
        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: how can I access ```@layout/drawer_heade``` items in activity

Answer (score 15):

The easier solution for me was:

**Considerations:**

- This solution requires autogenerated Navigation Drawer Activity
  provided by Android Studio.
- Classes `DrawerItem`, `CustomDrawerAdapter` and layout `custom_drawer_item.xml` were taken from [this tutorial](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/).

**1. Create this class for wrap the custom drawer item:**

```
public class DrawerItem {

  String ItemName;
  int imgResID;

  public DrawerItem(String itemName, int imgResID) {
        super();
        ItemName = itemName;
        this.imgResID = imgResID;
  }

  public String getItemName() {
        return ItemName;
  }
  public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        ItemName = itemName;
  }
  public int getImgResID() {
        return imgResID;
  }
  public void setImgResID(int imgResID) {
        this.imgResID = imgResID;
  }
}
```

**2. Create custom layout (custom_drawer_item.xml) for your drawer items:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="55dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_itemName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#DADADC">
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**3. Create your custom adapter:**

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerItem> {

Context context;
List<DrawerItem> drawerItemList;
int layoutResID;

public CustomDrawerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID, List<DrawerItem> listItems) {
    super(context, layoutResourceID, listItems);
    this.context = context;
    this.drawerItemList = listItems;
    this.layoutResID = layoutResourceID;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    DrawerItemHolder drawerHolder;
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        drawerHolder = new DrawerItemHolder();

        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
        drawerHolder.ItemName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_itemName);
        drawerHolder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon);

        view.setTag(drawerHolder);

    } else {
        drawerHolder = (DrawerItemHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    DrawerItem dItem = (DrawerItem) this.drawerItemList.get(position);

    drawerHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(
            dItem.getImgResID()));
    drawerHolder.ItemName.setText(dItem.getItemName());

    return view;
}

private static class DrawerItemHolder {
    TextView ItemName;
    ImageView icon;
}
}
```

**4. In autogenerated `NavigationDrawerFragment` class `onCreateView` method, replace the autogenerated adapter for this:**

```
ArrayList<DrawerItem> dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
dataList.add(new DrawerItem(getString(R.string.title_section1), R.drawable.ic_action_1));
dataList.add(new DrawerItem(getString(R.string.title_section2), R.drawable.ic_action_2));
dataList.add(new DrawerItem(getString(R.string.title_section3), R.drawable.ic_action_3));

mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new CustomDrawerAdapter(
        getActivity(),
        R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
        dataList));
```

Remember replace `R.string.title_sectionN` and `R.drawable.ic_action_N` for your own resources.

Answer (score 7):

You can easily customize the android Navigation drawer once you know how its implemented. here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) where you can set it up.

This will be the structure of your mainXML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You can customize this listview to your liking by adding the header. And radiobuttons.

Answer (score 3):

Android Navigation Drawer using Activity
I just followed the example :http://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/

You just need few Customization:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

public static final String AVATAR_URL = "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people/1/";


private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private View content;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    initToolbar();
    setupDrawerLayout();

    content = findViewById(R.id.content);
    drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
    final ImageView avatar = (ImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    Picasso.with(this).load(AVATAR_URL).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(avatar);


}


private void initToolbar() {
    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
    return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
}

   @Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
 private void setupDrawerLayout() {

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            int id = menuItem.getItemId();

          switch (id) {
                case R.id.drawer_home:
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                    break;
                case R.id.drawer_favorite:
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                    finish();
                    break;

            }


        return true;
    }
});
```

}
Here is the xml Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
```

Add drawer.xml in menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_home"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_favourite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/favourite"/>
    ...

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/settings"/>

</group>
```

To open  and close drawer add this values in string.xml

```
<string name="drawer_open">Open</string>
<string name="drawer_close">Close</string>
```

drawer.xml

```
enter code here
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/avatar"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_large"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/email"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_large"
    android:text="Username"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_large"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_large"
    android:text="username@mymail.com"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to add a header to categorize the list item in Drawer

Customize the `listView` or use `expandableListView`

> I need a radio button to select some of my options

You can do that without modifying the current implementation of `NavigationDrawer`, You just need to create a custom adapter for your `listView`. You can add a parent layout as `Drawer` then you can do any complex layouts within that as normal.

Comment: Please don't use the code tags for text which isn't code. In this case you should use blockquotes with the greater-than sign `>` like this `> This is a quote.` Have a look at the [Formatting help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)