# Android: How to get Google+ Profile Image and Cover Photo into Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, google-plus, navigation-drawer

Assuming the user is logged into their Google+ account on the phone, How can one get the Google+ Image (circular) and the Google+ Cover Photo into the Navigation Drawer of an Android app? Is there an API for this? Also, how can we display the profile photo as a circle? I am trying to achieve the same navigation drawer UI as the Android INBOX app.

Comment: You just have to see google+ documentation... https://developers.google.com/+/api/

All is explain. Speciallyhere : https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. You will need Enabling G+ API on google console.

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_1_enable_the_google_api

2. You will need to make custom navigation drawer:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

[How to create a custom navigation drawer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796209/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android)

3. You will need to initialize the GoogleApiClient

https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       ......
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .build();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(googleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);



        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(googleApiClient) != null) {
            Person person = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(googleApiClient);
            personNameView.setText(person.getDisplayName());
            if (person.hasImage()) {

                Person.Image image = person.getImage();


                new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

                        try {
                            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                            InputStream in = url.openStream();
                            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        /* TODO log error */
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                        personImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                }.execute(image.getUrl());
            }
       }
```

The whole example you can get here:
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

For cover photo you can do similar

```
Person.Cover.CoverPhoto cover = person.getCover().getCoverPhoto();
cover.getUrl()
```

4. Circle image

http://curious-blog.blogspot.com/2014/05/create-circle-bitmap-in-android.html

[How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: I have a similar issue resolved by getting URi from Google API, and then get from photo in profile information.

`.execute(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString());`