# How to get LARGE profile image via GoogleApiClient in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-play-services

I am getting G+ profile info along with image easily with the `GoogleApiClient` in android. Problem is, the image is very small (size=50) by default. And I am getting hard time to get the image with the size of my own choice. Is there any way I can specify the size using identity library?

NOTE: I am using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.8.0`.

Comment: This should help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033961/android-how-to-get-google-profile-image-and-cover-photo-into-navigation-drawer

Comment: You can take look at the official doc [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.Image). To resize the image and crop it to a square, append the query string ?sz=x, where x is the dimension in pixels of each side.

Comment: The doc is misleading. By default it put size ?sz=50. I just want to avoid string manipulation.

Comment: what about I want to get the large profile image without cropping to square (e.g. original image) please ?