# Why badge doesn't appear?

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

I try to make smth like this:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

To obtain this result I use this code:

I have my `NavigationView`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_second"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_third_drawer" />
```

I have menu `XML` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_inbox"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_mail_outline_white"
        android:title="Inbox"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/badge" />
</group>

<item android:title="@string/about_app">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_24dp"
            android:title="@string/about1" />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

And I have my `badge XML` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textMenuItemCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="rrrr"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:alpha="0.6"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I try to set `2` to `badge` in my `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainsecond);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    MenuItem item = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_inbox);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.badge);
    RelativeLayout notifCount = (RelativeLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    TextView tv = (TextView) notifCount.findViewById(R.id.textMenuItemCount);
    tv.setText("2");
}
```

And eventually I get nothing.

[image]

I have tried to debug and it show me all is ok.

[image]

Please help me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: verify visibility please.

Comment: @SohailZahid how i can do it?

Comment: after `setText("asdasd");` also set `setVisibility(0);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a custom navigation drawer in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796209/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android)

Comment: You can probably make a Fragment which looks similar to the navigation view, add a views to make a header and a list view for contents.Set this as your navigation views layout and you can be good to go.

Comment: @SohailZahid no it doesn't help me((

Comment: @Kushan i'm going to do this if won't get result with regular way

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko why didt you use prebuilt library for this.there are ton libs outside there.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko I am telling you from personal experience. If you need customizations, Do Not Waste time on using NavigationView. Almost always, it ends up being a time waste. Follow the links i have given. They give two different approaches to handle this issue. I personally find using a fragment much less restricting than customizing every adapter on earth to make the navigationview work :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option for you would be to provide a Fragment with the custom layout as the second child for your DrawerLayout instead of your NavigationView. It will basically look and work like a NavigationView but instead can give you a lot more customizations.

Follow Slidenerd Tutorial for this approach. Watch all videos to get total understanding :) :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWpEh9k8i7Q

If you still want to stick to using a NavigationView, check out the Duplicate Question which is basically what you have asked. It gives another approach.

[How to create a custom navigation drawer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796209/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this.

```
  TextView tv = (TextView) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_inbox).getActionView().findViewById((R.id.textMenuItemCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not find and manipulate views in `onCreate` , `onCreate` is called before `onCreateView` . Instead you should reference all your view's from `onResume` witch is called after the layout is properly inflated. Or you sould have the view setup before you passe it to `onCreate` .

Comment: Acctually i have tryed invoke this method after i opened `NavigationDrawer`. It means that `view` 100% had created, then i opened it and click button to set value and nothing