# Android - Custom open drawer view

Tags: android, xml, view, navigation

So, I did this in photoshop:

Is a navigationview:

[image]

But for some reason in android I get this:
[image]

My questions:

1: How can I change the title color of the menu?

This is my menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/grp1">
        <item android:title="LOREM IPSUM" android:id="@+id/menu_1">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
                    android:icon="@drawable/sharkred"
                    android:title="LOREM IPSUM" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
                    android:icon="@drawable/sharkblue"
                    android:title="LOREM IPSUM" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
                    android:icon="@drawable/sharkpink"
                    android:title="LOREM IPSUM" />
            </menu>
        </item>

    </group>

    <item android:title="LOREM IPSUM" android:id="@+id/action_divider"
        >
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/sharkyellow"
                android:title="LOREM IPSUM" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/sharkgreen"
                android:title="LOREM IPSUM" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="LOREM IPSUM"
        >
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share2"
                android:icon="@drawable/sharkgrey"
                android:title="LOREM IPSUM" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

2: How can I add a line separator below of the items and not the title? Is not a full line.
3: I added my icons to the menu.xml but the images are black.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for the #3:

```
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom Navigation drawer

Some of the useful links

- [http://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23632492/5612089)
- [http://www.tutecentral.com](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/)
- [https://www.youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zia_vSgYw8s)
- [http://www.recursiverobot.com/](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android)

Add your own layout for items for drawer

[image]