# How to add Cross Button at the top right corner of Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have created a navigation drawer,When user click on `hamburger` icon it opens the drawer. I need to add a close button in `drawer`. This is what i need to implement.

[image]

I have tried, bunt unable to add an image on the `Drawer Layout`. This is my code to add `Navigation Drawer`. Kindly guide me how to add an image at the top right corner of Drawer.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/base_layout">

    <include layout="@layout/header_layout"/>


</LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/sidebg"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:itemTextColor= "#ffffff"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        android:gravity="bottom|left"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>




</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

[ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) will fix your problem:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
                ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Alternative way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <!--your layout here -->
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/im_close_btn"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but still i am unable to understand that how to add `X` image at the top right corner

Comment: If you want to use ActionBarDrawerToggle make it RTL will fix your problem. alternative way is to put a close button in corner and when Drawer Open make it visible.

Comment: Thanks, let me try the Alternative approach

Comment: You're showing the v4 `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, whereas the OP mentions the hamburger icon, which is implemented in the v7 class. Also, the OP states that they want the close `Button` in the drawer, but that's not what your "Alternative way" demonstrates.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks, As I understood it's drawerLayout put whole screen so He needs a button to close a DrawerLayout so I suggest alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

Add a click listener to the imageview of the X icon.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    });
```

To add the icon you want to do a sort of custom view

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android-coding.blogspot.com" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android-coding"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="yourdrawable"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

See [My source](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2014/01/drawerlayout-with-custom-layoutview.html)

[Same as your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796209/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android)

Comment: but how to add image view at Navigation drawer

Comment: Ah yes see the updates. There is probably other ways of doing Custom views. That is the keyword you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
navigation_drawer_header.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/closeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="X"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code

```
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        Button closeButton = (Button) headerView.findViewById(R.id.closeButton);

        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to know how to add the "x" button. Well, Do you see the line below in your NavigationView :

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
```

This is the header layout of your drawer. Open this layout and put your ImageView in it. As simple as that.