# Navigation Drawer to store multiple choice and feed it into an array for API

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am adding a Navigation Drawer into my activity :

**Things I want to do :** Profile image which is up-loadable from mobile ***gallery*** and also from picture taken from ***camera*** instantly it should give option for cropping and fixing into circle transform I've to use glide that I know.

The Main part is to create an item name : INTERESTS(clickable and onClick its subItem(checkbox) scroll down) and if that's too much then just Item with INTEREST which is just a text and its subitem includes **CHECKBOXES**

One Button at the button of the drawer onClick of this button will save all responses into an array and feed it to ***api*** on drawer close.

https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_9/0Bx4BSt6jniD7YVdKQlF3TEo2S3M/patterns_navdrawer_behavior_persistent2.png

See this exactly the same but I don't want to navigate anywhere just list item should be chackboxes and save button at the buttom save store it in array so that I can feed it to the api onClick Button

Comment: first have a look at this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: I looked it and I know.....maybe I could do in a couple of days but in short span of time would be much appreciative

Comment: have you tried with navigation drawer activity provided by Android Studio

Comment: No I want customized drawer or slide menu and rest are mention in my question

Comment: you can have custom layout in navigation drawer. add the checkboxes for all required views and on click of button, get all the checked Items

Comment: Navigation drawer acitivity provided by android studio doesn't have menu items with submenu and how to upload image in profile image from gallery and no background image on header with height=" <padding bottom=5dp> profile image<padding up=5dp> " with name align left of image

Comment: @Vinodh can you provide some links where i could get something on it.

Comment: @SameerKhan : For requirements like this, better to go with custom layouts as in future if requirements change also, u could handle them easily with less work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796209/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: @Vinodh thank you and yeah you are right that's why I asked for Custom Navigation Drawer

Comment: @Vinodh See I have added image now I guess you get what I want OK? Please Help me how to do it.

Comment: @SamH67 : you need something like this : https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130077/discussion-between-samh67-and-vinodh).

Comment: @Vinodh Yeah I know but that's navigation I don't want to navigate anywhere just feed responses from checkBoxes to API that's just before saving obviously so there will be Onclick event for the button in navigation Drawer

Comment: @Vinodh I have started doing it keep you posted my work and please help where I need it