# Issue in Navigation Drawer menu items

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

Actually we have some text fields and icons in navigation menu drawer.we    want some text fields are become transparent color and remaining items are in full black color..only icons are become a transparent not text in my app.so any one fix this issue?

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="Dashboard" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_my_business"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_business_center_black_24dp"
        android:title="My Business" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_trending_gifs"
        android:icon="@drawable/trending_gifts"

        android:title="Trending Gifts" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_orders"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_description_black_24dp"
        android:title="Orders" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_cards"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_card_giftcard_black_24dp"
        android:title="E-Gift Cards &amp; Vouchers" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage_my_store"
        android:enabled="false"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_store_black_24dp"
        android:title="Manage my store" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_payments"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_payment_black_24dp"
        android:title="Payments" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_mnager"
        android:icon="@drawable/ads_manager"
        android:enabled="false"

        android:title="Ads Manager" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_reviews_ratings"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_rate_review_black_24dp"
        android:title="Reviews &amp; Ratings" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_wallet"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_balance_wallet_black_24dp"
        android:title="Wallet" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_help"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_help_black_24dp"
        android:title="Help/Support" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_about"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
        android:title="About" />
</group>
```

Comment: u just want to change color or disable click action?

Comment: You have to create custom drawer layout.

Here you go- http://stackoverflow.com/a/23632492/6676466

Comment: i want to change some text colors

Answer (score 0):

You can use tint color for icons to visible in any color. Something like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nvView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            **app:itemIconTint="@color/menu_icon"**
            app:itemBackground="@color/menu_group_colour"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            app:itemTextColor="#ffffff">

            <include layout="@layout/navigation_item"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```