# How to add more than one menu items in android navigation panel

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I want to add two icons(Facebook and twitter icons) in a single row in android naviagtion panel... can anybody know how to deal with that xml menu file?
here is the code of menu.xml file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:title="HOME" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_products"
            android:title="PRODUCTS" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_notes"
            android:title="NOTES" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_aboutus"
            android:title="ABOUT US" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_enq"
            android:title="ENQUIRY" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_news"
            android:title="NEWS" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_cal"
            android:title="CALCULATOR"
            />
</group>
</menu>
```

i want to add two buttons of social media sites after calculator button!!

Comment: You have to create custom Navigation Drawer to add two icons in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one option to use is `app:actionLayout` to insert the layout.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_home"
    android:title="Home"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/homeLayout" />
```

Create `homeLayout.xml` and simply add the icons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_facebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_twitter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_twitter" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: and what about onclick events?

Comment: Thanks I found where i have to add clicklisteners :-)...
thanks for ur quick response

Answer (score 1):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/facebook"
        android:icon="@drawable/fb"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Facebook"
      />

   <item android:id="@+id/twitter"
        android:icon="@drawable/twitter"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Twitter"
      />


</menu>
```

use this code..This worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try customizing the NavDrawer Layout such that it holds a listview or a recyclerview inside, then you can modify the rows in there.

A good tutorial for the same can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796209/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

Please use  Fontawesome library  i think that would solve the issue

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-fontawesome-in-an-android-app--cms-24167

Comment: The question is to add two icons in the same row