# How to make custom navigation drawer in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am designing custom navigation drawer like image shown below.I am using navigation drawer provided by the android studio but I need to change like this.How can I do this?[image]

Comment: check out this repo https://github.com/PHELAT/CustomNavigationDrawer

Comment: You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23632492/7413139) this is example is more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your talking about the magnification lense I think you would want to use something that captures the view as a bitmap and then crops and scales the bitmap. An example to covert a view could be this

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View v) {
   Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(),
   v.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
   v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width,
   v.getLayoutParams().height);
   v.draw(canvas);
   return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Then you would want to apply the bitmap to a canvas and then scale, crop and draw pond the canvas to get the desired look.

If you were just talking about the background then you would have to make a custom list view which there are plenty of tutorials already on
Here's a good link:  http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your navigation drawer with help of a listView or RecyclerView and creating a customAdapter for it. You can get help from this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/895942/Custom-Android-Navigation-Drawer)

Comment: I had gone through the some of tutorials which are based on the RecyclerView but list is not continue it for first it contains 2 items like general,security and for second it contains 6 items like timeline,sound,location

Comment: You can use different views instead of using a listView then, just take a LinearLayout and make similar type of view yourself and use it as your navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

i have much more Simpler way which wont cost you trouble.Take a look.This function should be under onCreate functions.

```
NavigationView rightNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_right_view);
        rightNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle Right navigation view item clicks here.
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Right Drawer - Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Right Drawer - Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Right Drawer - Help", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Right Drawer - About", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END); /*Important Line*/
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Now go to youe menu folder and create an xml file in which you can decide the looks of your Drawer layout[image: Your xml file under menu folder]