# How to make navigation menu item look like button?

Tags: android, navigationbar

I have side menu in my app that contain regular menu items, but `menu_button_enable_push` has to look like button. Tried to use `app:actionLayout`, but it has no effect. Any ideas how can it be done?

menu.xml

```
<menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="Домой" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cog"
        android:title="Настройки" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_info"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_question"
        android:title="Информация" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_button_enable_push"
        android:title="@string/button_enable_push"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_button"/>
</menu>
```

menu_button.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a custom navigation drawer in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796209/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android)