# Navigation drawer not wide enough

Tags: android

How can I make my navigation drawer as wide as [what is suggested](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-content) (like in the Gmail app)?

[image]

In my app it only extends to just over half of the screen.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.apple.bookshelf.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"  />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/authors_list_view"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: what does it look like in your app?

Comment: The same as above, but not as wide. It's the width of just over half the screen.

Comment: as per the official specs this is what the size should be `Maximum width: The maximum width of the nav drawer is 280dp on mobile and 320dp on tablet. This is calculated by multiplying the standard increment by five (the standard increment is 56dp on mobile and 64dp on tablet).` so set that width

Comment: I changed `android:layout_width="280dp"` on NavigationView but it didn't do anything

Comment: IIRC you change the drawer layout width

Comment: @Sebastian hope you found a solution, please let us know

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you could try to customize the Navigation drawer. The [official](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) documentation says

> If none of the prebuilt widgets or layouts meets your needs, you can
>   create your own View subclass.

you could think to create your [own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796209/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android) Navigation Drawer, here are offered several solutions, also the possibility to use libraries, you can see the source code, but also trying in the classical way, extending the class you need and override the methods you want to change