# How to add three items in same row in navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have navigation drawer. In which i have one header and other is items list.
Now the problem is how to add three items in a same row.Like

```
 Header xyz

    --------------------------
        Image   Text     Text    -----> row one
   ----------------------------- 
        iamge   text     text    ------> row two
    ----------------------------
        image   text     text    ------> row three
    ---------------------------
----- ....... so on
```

And when user click on the any item of the list that item should display on the header. Please guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796209/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You should create your custom navigation drawer then you can achieve your requirement. for more follow this tutorial http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/

May this help you.

Comment: This could be a comment, or post some relevant code. links may be expire in future.

Comment: Already am comented with duplicate answers contain same link you have answered so far.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use `NavigationView`

2.Add layout to `NavigationView`

3.add `RecyclerView` to layout (and set `GridLayoutManager`)

The important is use **inflateHeaderView** method in your code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_200"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_25"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**header_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity

```
View headview = mNavigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.header_layout);
TextView tvHeader = (TextView) headview.findViewById(R.id.tv_header);
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) headview.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , please check i have edited my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just add a item in the header .And set it gone.Then it you click one item .Then set value to header item .And set it visible .