# TextView instead of icon in navigation drawer

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

Im trying to change the icon to TextView and color it's background.
Actually i have icon on the left side of item, and the text with colored background on the right, using android:actionLayout.

[image]

And i want to delete the icon on the left side, and place there a text with colored background which i have currently on right side.

Any possibility?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to create your own Navigation drawer adapter. Check answers in this thread to understand how to do it.

[How to create a custom navigation drawer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796209/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android)

Comment: Ah, i thought i could avoid this one, but if there isn't other choice

Comment: I was stuck in a similar situation. I couldn't do it without implementing my own adapter.