# How to edit the color.xml in androidStudio 3.0.1

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have designed my color file from the Color Tool from android and exported the same from there. But when I replace the file with the existing one.

## It is showing the following error stack trace...

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\LENOVO\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\fe9fe9aedd60d1d8fd516975c2138d20\res\values\values.xml
Error:error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryLight (aka com.example.lenovo.jdstudio:attr/colorPrimaryLight)' not found.
Error:error: style attribute 'attr/colorSecondary (aka com.example.lenovo.jdstudio:attr/colorSecondary)' not found.
Error:error: style attribute 'attr/colorSecondaryLight (aka com.example.lenovo.jdstudio:attr/colorSecondaryLight)' not found.
Error:error: style attribute 'attr/colorSecondaryDark (aka com.example.lenovo.jdstudio:attr/colorSecondaryDark)' not found.
Error:error: style attribute 'attr/primaryTextColor (aka com.example.lenovo.jdstudio:attr/primaryTextColor)' not found.
Error:error: style attribute 'attr/secondaryTextColor (aka com.example.lenovo.jdstudio:attr/secondaryTextColor)' not found.
F:\JDStudio\code\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Error:(1899) style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryLight (aka com.example.lenovo.jdstudio:attr/colorPrimaryLight)' not found.
Error:(1901) style attribute 'attr/colorSecondary (aka com.example.lenovo.jdstudio:attr/colorSecondary)' not found.
Error:(1902) style attribute 'attr/colorSecondaryLight (aka com.example.lenovo.jdstudio:attr/colorSecondaryLight)' not found.
Error:(1903) style attribute 'attr/colorSecondaryDark (aka com.example.lenovo.jdstudio:attr/colorSecondaryDark)' not found.
Error:(1904) style attribute 'attr/primaryTextColor (aka com.example.lenovo.jdstudio:attr/primaryTextColor)' not found.
Error:(1905) style attribute 'attr/secondaryTextColor (aka com.example.lenovo.jdstudio:attr/secondaryTextColor)' not found.
Error:failed linking references.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 57s
Information:17 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

## Deafault colors.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3f51b5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="content">#F5F5F5</color>>
</resources>
```

## The one which I want to replace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="colorPrimary">#0091ea</color>
  <color name="colorPrimaryLight">#64c1ff</color>
  <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#0064b7</color>
  <color name="colorSecondary">#263238</color>
  <color name="colorSecondaryLight">#4f5b62</color>
  <color name="colorSecondaryDark">#000a12</color>
  <color name="primaryTextColor">#fafafa</color>
  <color name="secondaryTextColor">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

## styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryLight">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryLight">@color/colorSecondaryLight</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryDark">@color/colorSecondaryDark</item>
        <item name="primaryTextColor">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
        <item name="secondaryTextColor">@color/secondaryTextColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

## I also tried to change android:theme attribute in the AndroidMainfest.xml file like

```
android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
```

Comment: You have not kept `<color name="content">#F5F5F5</color>` in the new file.

Comment: Can you show an example of a style file where this colors are used?

Comment: You have also not kept colorAccent.

keep all the default colors in the file, and add yours to them, clean the project, build it and try again.

Comment: you have to keep the colors file as it is, then try to add the new colors you want or change the value of the colors that you need to change value for, as may be there is some issue in new file naming or some missing colors that it can't find

Comment: it is working for the two colors i.e. colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark but  not  for other colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use android studio style editor. It is more simple and automatically change your colors. 
You should define your style in *style.xml* and define colors in *color.xml*
and also don't replace files with the original one you may get lots of errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i have did the changes form the theme  editor. So it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this line in **colors.xml**

```
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
```

Or you need to another colour as an **accent colour** in style.xml.

```
<style name="AppTheme_Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/abc1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/abc2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/abc3</item>
</style>
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: from where should i remove the Android?

Comment: @AakashBidlan I've updated my answer please check and try it

Comment: how could i add other color it will add only 3 color but i want 8 colors in my theme

Comment: Define any color from your colors.xml inside, i.e. you have to define **primaryTextColor** in yours colors.xml. So you can define this colour as a default accentColour for whole app.

`<item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryTextColor</item>`