# Show ListView Items in Nevigation Drawer to fetch from MySQL Database Android

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have a problem regarding to Android and MySQL Databse. I got the items from database to Android Activity in listview but i want that items in the Android Navigation Drawer. Please give me any suggestion or reference of web pages..

This ListView is in Activity

[image: This ListView is in Activity]

And I want those items in the below navigation drawer at the place of Item1, Item2, and so on..

[image: Item List Category]
 Thanks

Comment: You need to use custom drawer activity for this purpose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a custom navigation drawer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796209/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android)

Comment: Check this link http://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-custom-navigation-drawer-example/

Comment: Thanks Vishva, but I need Fetching and adding programming logic to navigation drawer. Its easy to fetch and show in Activity but I want solution for Adding in Drawer. I updated my question, added 2nd Image

Comment: So this link has same example. just where it is using static data for listview replace that with your arraylist

Comment: Ok, thanks again. :)

Comment: in this line `ItemArrayAdapter itemArrayAdapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, numbers);` replace number with your arraylist

Comment: are you there Vishva??

Comment: I got error in `drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_menu, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)` this line which shows where we write down R.drawable.ic_menu ,instead of this we have to use widget.Toolbar

Comment: Sorry don't know much about this actually. I don't have good experience with navigation drawers :( :( Try to ask a question with all the details properly. what you have tried and error and link you prefered all that. you will get answer by someone

Comment: ok thanks.. i ll create toolbar then it may be solved.

Comment: btw are you developer at stackoverflow??

Comment: sorry, I mean , R u working with stackoverflow team?? bcoz everytime I post question , I get ur reply very fast..

Comment: That is good for Us :)

Comment: and i add custom toolbar to the program and its working fine..