# How to create a sliding drawer like Gmail in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-xml

I was working on an application where I need to create a custom  sliding drawer how to create one. similar to gmail's sliding drawer...[image]

Comment: Seems like already have a api for this view. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer

Comment: I have used the following drawers but there is no clue how to customise and make it more colourful and more like the above given drawer, Is there any way I can make it more similar to it.

Comment: So much ways u can do this , such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796209/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android/23632492)